# is it possible to achieve without using multiple media queries/elements for ordering nested columns/rows in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

this is my page structure

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:20px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="height:80px">
          1st
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="height:50px">
          3rd
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="height:50px">
          5th
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="height:50px">
          2nd
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="height:40px">
          4th
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="height:90px">
          6th
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made a jsFiddle for it
https://jsfiddle.net/ytke8mn3/

I marked the columns with 1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th

The issue I'm facing is after resizing my page to a certain width in bootstrap below 992px.

I would like the columns to show in this order > 1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th 
rather than 1st 3rd 5th 2nd 4th 6th

How to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into flexbox for this (as Bootstrap makes use of this): https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Mr. Twix, you want to use compulsory boostrap row column method?

Comment: @Barrosy that's a very good concept, thank you. it resolved the ordering. however it created the problem with spaces between columns as you can see in this https://jsfiddle.net/5kwg78vy/

Comment: @Saravana I don't know what that means x.x

Comment: I can try using ul li. is that okay?

Comment: @Twixxie You could try to nest the elements (I always try to refrain from styling Bootstrap rows, columns and anything else related to Bootstrap's layout system): https://jsfiddle.net/snhj0mLe/ I am aware it is not exactly working like your first given example, but at least this shows it is possible to get rid of the space. I will see if I can edit the fiddle so that it will work accordingly to your requirement.

Comment: @Barrosy thanks for your response, yes this looks a little better, however I can't control the sizes of those elements, some of them are 800px in the website I'm working on. if I make them equal sizes. it'll not look proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that worked for me, it aligned the elements very well for me. I'm happy with it so far. it required a little bit of dom element restructuring(less written code) but that's okay.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:20px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" style="height:80px">1st</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:40px">2nd</div>
    <div class="col-md-8" style="height:40px">3rd</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:80px">4th</div>
    <div class="col-md-8" style="height:80px">5th</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:30px">6th</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://github.com/desandro/masonry

I don't know how it is implemented but it's working. below is a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/p5u976mt/

Comment: I still recommend to not use any styling on the layout elements of bootstrap because those are not made for re-styling purpose (e.g. any `<div>` element containing `col-md-*` or `row` classes). Animation aside this looks like what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Barrosy the style "height" on those divs are only done to present my issue in jsfiddle, without them the divs will not be properly presented to you all. that's the reason I used those. but in my real code, I have content within those divs, it takes care of the height.

Comment: You would rather want to create an element within a column element (which would also reside in a row element in Bootstrap), although I get your point.

Answer (score 0):

The outer containers col-md-8 and col-md-4 make it impossible to reorder it the way you want to with https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes

You could [hide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) the two outer containers and show a third one only for narrow device-widths with the 6 elements in the right order (would be very easy but a bad practice, because you repeat yourself).

Comment: What you are saying is true, but you are not providing an example solution (or alternative) thus this cannot be seen as an answer. Please provide any code and update your answer.

Comment: yes I get what you're saying. but I would like to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly your actual requirement is. You can try the following bootstrap structure to get this ordering correctly.
[Fiddle goes here](https://jsfiddle.net/r29afzg4/)

```
.row {
 background: #f8f9fa;
 }

 .row > div {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  }
```

Comment: yes this makes the ordering of columns correct. however if columns have different heights, it would create empty spaces which I would like filled. please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6Lz3o2y0/